# How to run SuperHot at full screen on a Mac?

Tags: macos, monitor, superhot

I have SuperHot downloaded through Steam, and am attempting to play it on my 1080p external monitor. It launches [windowed at less than 1080p](http://www.izaaklauer.com/s/SuperHotWindowed.png), and I don't see a setting to adjust the resolution or switch out of windowed mode.

I'm running a 15" retina Macbook Pro with OS X 10.11.3.

Comment: My current workaround is to use the system accessibility zoom, but it's less than optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, like in most Mac apps.

Comment: Well, now i'm embarrassed.  The green maximize button was disabled, so I had assumed that it wouldn't respond to Cmd+F.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

For people who still looking for an answer:

On first enter there is an option window. To get it back run app with ALT held.